# Toggle two different elements in DataTemplate using Style Triggers

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, datatrigger, wpf-style

I have an object in ViewModel whose properties are displayed by a datatemplate. The screen also has a button toggling the `IsEditing` flag in ViewModel, which should make the object properties editable, like the following:

- Name should change from TextBlock to TextBox;
- Color should change from colored rectangle to ComboBox with color options;
- Category should change from TextBlock to ComboBox;

I know how to implement this with two completely independent DataTemplates, using a Style and a DataTrigger to toggle between them:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding FancyObject}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DisplayTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsEditing, ElementName=UserControl}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

And currently the `DisplayTemplate` is like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DisplayTemplate" DataType="my:FancyObject">
    <Border>
        <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding Metadata}">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Border>           
            <DataGrid
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding FancyObjectCollection}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <!-- Text and Template columns -->
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid> 
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>                   
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem is: using two independent but similar templates would mean a duplication of layout, since only some fields would change, but the overall structure is the same.

Another option I imagine is to use a single template defined inside the Style, and use the Trigger to change the fields individually, but I don't know how to do it, or even if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one template.
In the template add both TextBlock and TextBox, same for all your other controls on the original template.
Bind the controls visibility to bool to visibility converter. (Or use triggers) Only one set of your control will be seen each time (based on IsEditing flag)

Comment: Hmm, that is a good idea! I got a working option by using `ContentControl` with Style (just as the example in my question) for EVERY field in the form, but that quickly became a mess! Your alternative is much better! Will think about it tomorrow at work and then come to post some feedback. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your solution is simple and solved the problem avoiding A LOT of boilerplate... Thanks!

Comment: (well, but in the end I used a single ComboBox right away, only styled in such a way that it looks like a TextBlock when disabled, making background and borderbrush transparent).

Answer (score 0):

The ControlTemplate is only used upon generating the UI Elements. If you change the template AFTER generating the items, the generated items will not change.

You can also not use a trigger to change a TextBox to a TextBlock and vice versa.

Your only option is indeed to mirror the layout twice and hide/display it via the data bound property.